# Answers in questions / answer level of quiz not being read in correctly sometimes

Tags: c#

I am creating a question and answer level for a school project where we have to make a quiz. It seems that sometimes the questions and answers are being read in correctly but sometimes the questions and answers aren't - even on the first attempt. I am not sure why the questions and answers aren't being read in correctly.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace frmSplashScreen
{
    public partial class frmLevel3 : Form
    {
        public frmLevel3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int questionsshown = 1; //to go up to 4
        int questionno = 0;


        public void randomq() //new question function... generating number, using it as index, putting it on lblQ
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            questionno = ran.Next(20);
            lblQ.Text = gameClass.questions[questionno];
            gameClass.questions.RemoveAt(questionno);
        }

        private void frmLevel3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // Load //
        {
            gameClass.time = 16;
            tmrCountdown.Start();
            this.BackgroundImage = gameClass.background; //settings bg
            btnNext.Hide();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("l3questions.txt")) //reading all questions from text file
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    gameClass.questions.Add(line);
                }

            }
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("l3answers.txt")) //reading all answers from text file
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    gameClass.answers.Add(line);
                }
            }
            randomq();

            if (gameClass.background != null)
            {
                lblQ.ForeColor = Color.White;
                lblScore.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Next Button //
        {
            if (questionsshown < 4)
            {
                questionsshown++;
                randomq();
                gameClass.time = 15;
                tmrCountdown.Start();
                gameClass.answers.RemoveAt(questionno);
                btnNext.Hide();
                btnCheck.Show();
            }
            if (questionsshown >= 4) // Checking no. of questions shown 
            {
                tmrCountdown.Stop();
                frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu(); //Go to Menu
                this.Hide();
                MessageBox.Show("You have completed level 3 with a score of " + gameClass.score);
                menu.Show();
            }

            txt1a.BackColor = Color.White; //Setting txts back to normal
            txt1a.Text = null;
        }

        public void check()
        {
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
            gameClass.time = 15;

            btnCheck.Hide();
            btnNext.Show();
            if (txt1a.Text.ToLower() == gameClass.answers[questionno]) //checking question
            {
                gameClass.score++;
                lblScore.Text = "Score: " + gameClass.score.ToString();
                txt1a.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                txt1a.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Check Button //
        {
            check();

        }

        private void picHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmHelp help = new frmHelp();
            this.Hide();
            help.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void picHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
            frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
            this.Hide();
            menu.Show();

        }

        private void lblQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void menuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
            this.Hide();
            menu.Show();
        }

        private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmHelp help = new frmHelp();
            this.Hide();
            help.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void level1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmLevel1 l1 = new frmLevel1();
            this.Hide();
            l1.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void level2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmLevel2 l2 = new frmLevel2();
            this.Hide();
            l2.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void logOutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
            this.Hide();
            login.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void tmrCountdown_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            gameClass.time--;
            lblCountdown.Text = "Time left: " + gameClass.time.ToString();

            if (gameClass.time == 0 && this.Name == "frmLevel3")
            {
                tmrCountdown.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("You have run out of time!");
                questionsshown++;
                check();
            }
            label1.Text = this.Name;

        }
    }
}
```

It was working perfectly before I started using a timer to count down from 15 to add bit more of a challenge to the level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This would be a perfect point in time to look up how to use a debugger.

Comment: "Why is this code not working" is an off-topic question on Stackoverflow. If you're getting any errors, or have more concrete data that shows what is going wrong or not, we might be able to help. Just set breakpoints and see what's going on, we are not here to make guesses based on your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by putting the current question and current answer in variables and using that to check instead.

Here is my new, working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace frmSplashScreen
{
    public partial class frmLevel3 : Form
    {
        public frmLevel3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int questionsshown = 0; //to go up to 4
        int questionno = 0;
        string currentq = null;
        string currenta = null;


        public void randomq() //new question function... generating number, using it as index, putting it on lblQ
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            questionno = ran.Next(20);
            currentq = gameClass.questions[questionno];
            currenta = gameClass.answers[questionno];
            lblQ.Text = currentq;

            gameClass.questions.RemoveAt(questionno);
            gameClass.answers.RemoveAt(questionno);
        }

        private void frmLevel3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // Load //
        {
            gameClass.time = 16;
            tmrCountdown.Start();
            this.BackgroundImage = gameClass.background; //settings bg
            btnNext.Hide();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("l3questions.txt")) //reading all questions from text file
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    gameClass.questions.Add(line);
                }

            }
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("l3answers.txt")) //reading all answers from text file
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    gameClass.answers.Add(line);
                }
            }


            if (gameClass.background != null)
            {
                lblQ.ForeColor = Color.White;
                lblScore.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }

            randomq();

            Console.WriteLine(currentq);
            Console.WriteLine(currenta);
            Console.WriteLine(questionno);
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Next Button //
        {
            if (questionsshown >= 4) // Checking no. of questions shown 
            {
                tmrCountdown.Stop();
                frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu(); //Go to Menu
                this.Hide();
                MessageBox.Show("You have completed level 3 with a score of " + gameClass.score);
                menu.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                questionsshown++;
                gameClass.time = 16;
                btnNext.Hide();
                btnCheck.Show();
                randomq();
                tmrCountdown.Start();
            }

            txt1a.BackColor = Color.White; //Setting txts back to normal
            txt1a.Text = null;
            Console.WriteLine(currentq);
            Console.WriteLine(currenta);
            Console.WriteLine(questionno);
        }

        public void check()
        {
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
            gameClass.time = 16;

            btnCheck.Hide();
            btnNext.Show();
            if (txt1a.Text.ToLower() == currenta) //checking question
            {
                gameClass.score++;
                lblScore.Text = "Score: " + gameClass.score.ToString();
                txt1a.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                txt1a.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Check Button //
        {
            check();

        }

        private void picHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmHelp help = new frmHelp();
            this.Hide();
            help.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void picHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
            frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
            this.Hide();
            menu.Show();

        }

        private void lblQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void menuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
            this.Hide();
            menu.Show();
        }

        private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmHelp help = new frmHelp();
            this.Hide();
            help.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void level1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmLevel1 l1 = new frmLevel1();
            this.Hide();
            l1.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void level2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmLevel2 l2 = new frmLevel2();
            this.Hide();
            l2.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void logOutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
            this.Hide();
            login.Show();
            tmrCountdown.Stop();
        }

        private void tmrCountdown_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            gameClass.time--;
            lblCountdown.Text = "Time left: " + gameClass.time.ToString();

            if (gameClass.time == 0 && this.Name == "frmLevel3")
            {
                tmrCountdown.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("You have run out of time!");
                questionsshown++;
                check();
            }
            label1.Text = this.Name;

        }
    }
}
```